# Media Upload , file name changed automatically

Tags: php, customization, javascript

I face a problem that when i upload a video that named in non-english language , for example : Arabic , it placed in uploads folder with strange name

> ÙÙŠØ¯ÙŠÙˆÙˆÙˆ

so it can't be access through the website and give me error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

So , how can i fix this error.
the encoding used in my website UTF8